# getBoundingClientRect() returns the same values for all elements

Tags: d3.js, getboundingclientrect

I am creating a legend for my chart.  I need to dynamically select x values for the different elements, based on the width of the preceding element.  I am using getBoundingClientRect() for this.  The problem is that it is returning the same values for all the different elements(The value of the first element).  I am logging it to console.

```
var primaryTotal = legend.append('text')
    .attr("x", function () {
        console.log(nameText.node().getBoundingClientRect());
        return ((nameText.node().getBoundingClientRect().right)+100);
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text(function (d) {

        return d["total"] + " " + parameter[DS1].units_scaled;
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d["colour"];
    })
```

nameText is the element that I am drawing before primaryTotal.

```
    var legend = groups.selectAll('.legend')
    .data(rowObjectArray)
    .enter()
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        // console.log(d);
        // console.log(i);
        return "translate(0," + ((i * 20) + 20) + ")";
    })
```

I am appending it to the group created here.

```
var legendRect = legend.append('rect')
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -10)
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {
        return d["colour"];
    })

var nameText = legend.append('text')
    .attr("x", function () {
        return (legendRect.node().getBoundingClientRect().right);
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text(function (d) {
        return d["name"];
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d["colour"];
    })
```

declaration of nameText and legendRect.  They are both elements I am using in my legend.

This is what is getting logged to console....

[console log showing the getBoundingClientRect() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svpGQ.png)

Don't know how to proceed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Since the problem seems to be that `nameText` is always the same element, it would help a lot if you could show its declaration and how it is expected to be updated.

Comment: @Kaiido  I am appending each element of my legend to the 'legend' element that takes in an array as a dataset.  The array . (rowObjectArray) contains the data that I want to display in my legend.

Comment: I found a temporary fix to it...I don't think it is efficient though..  I am creating arrays that store the element objects and then extracting the getBoundingClientRect().right value from it once it is done being plotted.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating arrays that store the element objects and then extracting the getBoundingClientRect().right value from it once it is done being plotted.

```
 var nameTextCoordArray = [];
var nameTextArray = [];
count = 0;

var nameText = legend.append('text')
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return (rectCoordArray[i]);
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text(function (d) {
        nameTextArray[count] = this;
        count = (count + 1);
        return d["name"];
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d["colour"];
    })

nameTextCoordArray = getCoordArray(nameTextArray);


var primaryTotal = legend.append('text')
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return d3.max(nameTextCoordArray);
    })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .text(function (d) {
        primaryTotalArray[count] = this;
        count = (count + 1);
        return d["total"] + " " + parameter[DS1].units_scaled;
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d["colour"];
    })
```

The getCoordArray method:

```
var getCoordArray = function (array) {

var returnArray = [];

for (x in array) {
    returnArray[x] = (array[x].getBoundingClientRect().right + 20);
}
return returnArray;
```

}

If Anyone can come up with a more efficient solution, please share...Thanks